# Why do I get 'Unresolved external symbol' with default keyword

Tags: c++, c++11

I've defined a template class in a header file and instantiated it explicitly.

```
template<platform_render_api TRenderApi>
class platform_buffer : public iresource
{
public:
    platform_buffer();
...
```

I put it's definition in a .cpp file but I get unresolved external error for every function that I've used `default` keyword for it's definition.

```
template< >
GRAPHICIMP_DLL_EXP // vc++ dll-export
platform_buffer<g_api_dx11>::platform_buffer() = default;
```

I want to know why I get error for `default` functions?

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you try it in the *header* instead ?

Comment: Do you get the same error with a non-`default` constructor? (Change `= default;` to `{ }`.) I wouldn't expect `default` to make any difference here.

Comment: With function body `{}` i don't get error for that type.

Comment: @WhozCraig In a header every thing seems ok.

Comment: What version of VS is this?

Comment: Since in this context, `= default;` and `{ }` are supposed to do the same thing, I'd say to just use `{ }` instead, but that's a workaround, it doesn't explain why `= default;` doesn't work.

Comment: But I'm curious about it :)

Comment: There's a reason I didn't post it as an answer. :) I'm curious too.

Comment: That is strange. A lot has improved here with VS. You may have to file a bug report on connect.microsoft.com. Do you have a MCVE of the issue (with command lines etc.) to reproduce the issue on a smaller scale?

Comment: There is a difference between the `=default` being inside vs outside the class definition, but I'm sure that isn't enough to cause this error.

Comment: If I can't figure out the problem I'll report it

Comment: If you do figure it out come back and post an answer. If it is filed, please post the link here as well, I'd like to follow this.

Comment: @Niall I report it with an attachment sample - https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/2457178